# how to do simple navigation in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have a todo list app built in react js? I want it so that when people click on the title they see the todo item by itself. How do I do simple navigation in ReactJS?

My idea was doing something like this

Have a Todo class and when someone clicks on a todo, it goes to this.handleclick that calls this.props.handleClick eventually going back to the App Class that loads the todo item.

Comment: There are a few sample todo apps already available for reactjs - http://todomvc.com/examples/react/#/. Full tutorial at: https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use some routing library. Look at [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router)

Comment: If you don't want or need deep linking (the ability to access different parts of your app with different url segments), then an event dispatcher is all you need. There are a few event emitter modules written for nodejs also work in the browser. For instance, https://github.com/asyncly/EventEmitter2